# What is the difference between Linux Kernel 5.3.0-1039-gke and 4.15.0-124-generic?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, kernel

A few months ago I bought two used Dell Optiplex machines for use as a NAS and internet gateway, respectively.

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on both of them, and I noticed that even though the exact same version of Ubuntu was installed on both (Ubuntu Server 18.04.5 LTS), neither of them have any packages that can be upgraded, and the hardware is also the exact same between both machines (only difference is the NAS has a larger SSD and more RAM than the gateway, everything else is the same), these two machines have different kernel versions.

I know very little about the Linux kernel or what its different versions means. I'm curious what is the difference between Linux Kernel version `5.3.0-1039-gke` (the one which is installed on my NAS) and Linux Kernel `4.15.0-124-generic` (the one installed on my gateway). Also possibly worth mentioning that neither of these machines came with an OS installed (or hard disk).

Both of these are running the same Ubuntu installation that I flashed onto a USB flash drive, both were installed onto new, fresh/blank SSDs. What is the difference between these two kernels, why are the kernels different on hardware that is the same, and is either of these kernels better than the other?

Comment: I have [posted an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1606619/167207), but when you say, “I bought two used Dell Optiplex machines…” does that mean that physical hardware is 100% the same between the two? The disparity between kernel versions is quite odd. I would not worry about it to be honest, but a disparity like that points to the systems having something fundamentally different on a hardware level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It seems like these two machines have different hardware — BIOS settings or something else — despite your implication that both machines are similar.

In general, the kernel that is installed on the system is the kernel that the system should be using. Which sounds odd to say, but that is basically it.

What is odd in your case is the disparity between two kernels for each Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS install. One is `5.3.0-1039-gke` and the other is `4.15.0-124-generic`. This is what I know:

- `5.3.0-1039-gke`: As far as I know the `gke` stands for “Google Kubernetes Engine” and it would seem that kernel is specific for that usage? Odd that you have that installed on a desktop system.
- `4.15.0-124-generic`: That `generic` is what it means… That is a generic version of the Kernel for that install.

In general those appended designations of `-gke` and `-generic` can be read as:

> “That is the optimized Kernel for those those specifications: `-gke` for one and `-generic` for another.”

That said, whet you say this:

> “A few months ago I bought two used Dell Optiplex machines for use as a NAS and internet gateway, respectively.”

While your post implies both machines are 100% the same, my personal feeling is something is different between the two of them. Perhaps the motherboards or BIOS’s are different? That is the only rational explanation I can see for why there is such a wide disparity between kernel versions here.

In general though, I would not sweat it. Yes, kernel updates are important… But mainly in the context of servers that are exposed to the world. If these are just two personal machines I highly doubt you will notice a difference between the two boxes. Just enjoy them!

---

**UPDATE**: According to [a comment left by the original poster](https://superuser.com/questions/1606611/what-is-the-difference-between-linux-kernel-5-3-0-1039-gke-and-4-15-0-124-generi/1606619#comment2449412_1606619), the `linux-image-gke-5.3` kernel was installed when [WireGuard](https://www.wireguard.com) was installed for some reason. So this was not an issue with hardware or BIOS but rather with WireGuard’s own install process.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I checked both machines specs which are all identical (except for RAM and disk size) and both machines also have the same model number. It looks like you are correct about the two machines having different BIOS versions. I ran the command "sudo dmidecode -s bios-version" on both machines and it appears that the machine used as a gateway with the 4.x kernel has version "A16" while the NAS machine with 5.x kernel has version "A13" . I wonder why, hopefully that isn't a cause for concern.

Comment: One other thing I'm curious about is whether the NAS machine will have any effects/issues due to having a GKE kernel, and if it does, should I/could I install the generic kernel onto it instead? Also I forgot to mention in my original post this is not a desktop machine, they're both running in a headless configuration, only accessing them through SSH, and they are running the server edition of Ubuntu 18.04.5 if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Computer_User First, glad to hear this answer solved your issue! It still is weird to see that one has one kernel and another has another. At this point, I would think two things: First, it’s no big deal. Second, I would personally prefer both machines have the same kernels installed. So your choice, but at this point it might be the best/safest option to reinstall Ubuntu on the NAS machine. But I would also see if you can upgrade the BIOS on that machine before anything else. And yes, not desktops but servers but that’s no big difference. Just see if you can get the BIOS updated.

Comment: I figured it out!  I ran aptitude why linux-image-gke-5.3 and found that the 5.3.0-gke kernel was installed when I installed WireGuard for some reason, oddly on none of my other linux machines was a GKE installed with WireGuard. Went and booted into 4.15.0 manually and then uninstalled the GKE kernel, rebooted and all is well, now they are both running the same kernel.

Comment: @Computer_User Wow! Now that is some good detective work! Both on `4.15.0-124-generic` now? Cool. FWIW, it seems like WireGuard *might* need `linux-image-gke-5.3` for some reason. Check out the Google searches for “[WireGuard linux-image-gke-5.3](https://www.google.com/search?q=WireGuard+linux-image-gke-5.3)” and see if it means much to you. My gut feeling is you should be fine unless you are doing some deeper/non-standard config setup with WireGuard.